# Is This "Idiom" Well-Defined?

Tags: c++

Let's say I have a C library that has its own (de)initialization routine, as many of them do.

```
init_API();

deinit_API();
```

now let's say I want to provide another level of abstraction to the user, and abstract away these calls, using a class that's instantiated statically. The method I was thinking of:

```
struct API_initializer{
    API_initializer(){
        init_API();
        if(API_init_failure)
            throw (APIFailureException); //important
    }

    ~API_initializer(){
        deinit_API();
    }
};

struct API_initializer_holder{
    static API_initializer initializer;
};
```

Now, my question is, is this well-defined behavior? I.E., will the static constructor be called at some reasonable point, and will all the (static) variables the C API need be initialized properly? In addition, is it bad practice to throw an exception that the user has no way of catching?

Comment: Why is the class `static`?

Comment: @Csq, I think OP just meant static object, so it'd be initialized before `main` and cleaned up after.

Comment: @chris I still don't like this `static` member in the struct. E.g. what can possibly catch the exception thrown by `API_initializer`'s constructor?

Comment: @Csq, Well, that's the question.

Comment: Unless you instantiate the holder somewhere nothing will happen.  What would you expect to happen if you instantiated more than one holder?  This seems like all kinds of bad idea to me.

Comment: @retired ninja: it is a static instance; no matter how many i make, there will only be one API_initializer. if you mean the actual API_initializer class, i could just hide the constructors and make it a friend or something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is covered by §3.6.2 [basic.start.init]/p4-6 of the standard:

> It is implementation-defined whether the dynamic initialization of a
>   non-local variable with static storage duration is done before the
>   first statement of `main`. If the initialization is deferred to some
>   point in time after the first statement of main, it shall occur before
>   the first odr-use of any function or variable defined in the same
>   translation unit as the variable to be initialized.<sup>35</sup>
>
> [...]
>
> If the initialization of a non-local variable with static or thread storage duration exits via an exception, `std::terminate` is called.
>
> <sup>35</sup> A non-local variable with static storage duration having initialization with side-effects must be initialized even if it is not odr-used.

As there's no way your static object can be in the same translation unit as a function in the C library you are wrapping, the only way to guarantee initialization would be to define it in the same translation unit as `main()`, which doesn't strike me as adding any kind of convenience to the end user.

In any event, it's probably not a good idea to cause `std::terminate` to be called by throwing an exception if initialization fails. The end user probably want to do better error handling than that.

Comment: great, thanks. i appreciate the quote from the Standard.

Comment: You're neglecting the fact that code in C can't have dynamic initialization, so there can be no order of initialization issues with regards to it.  (The reason you have functions like `init_API` is because C does not support dynamic initialization of objects with static lifetime.)

Comment: @JamesKanze Um, what does that have to do with anything? The goal is to get the object constructed, and `Init_API` called, before any other functions from the C library are called, and you can only guarantee that by either 1) defining the object in the translation unit defining those functions (impossible) or 2) defining the object in the translation unit defining `main()`...

Answer (score 3):

In my experience it is a bad idea to try and rely on static initialization order.

A better idea would be to get rid of the holder, and just go:

```
int main()
{
    API_initializer foo;

    // rest of program
}
```

If you really want it to throw on failure then include a try..catch block.

NB. Make the class non-copyable to prevent accidents.

Comment: Great idea, I'll probably end up going with that technique.

Comment: This is probably the best solution.  If you're paranoid, of course, you'll make the class non-copiable _and_ a singleton in the original sense (i.e. it allows one, and only one instance).

Answer (score 2):

No, the program will break if the initialization is failed. You cannot catch the exception and handle it because the global variables(static member data) is initialized before `main()`.

It's better to call `init_API()` and `deinit_API()` in `main()`.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is: it depends.  If the external API is implemented
in C (so that it will have no dynamic initialization), and it is
not used in any of your static initializers (which should be the
case, since there is no way that they can safely do `init_API`),
then the idiom is more or less safe (except that you shouldn't
allow an exception to escape from a static initializer.  Whether
it is a good idea or not is another question; if the
initialization can fail, you may not want to execute it before
you can catch and handle the error, which means that you're in
`main`.